# System of (in)equalities in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, finite-groups

In the sequel, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denotes the cyclic group of integers modulo $p$.

Working to a problem in Algebraic Geometry, I was led to state the following

**Conjecture.** Given every positive integer $b \geq 2$ and every odd prime $p$, it is possible to find *non-zero* elements $$\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_b, \, \; \mu_1, \ldots, \mu_b \in \mathbb{Z}_p$$ such that
\begin{cases} \sum_{i=1}^b \lambda_i =1 \\ \sum_{i=1}^b \mu_i =1 \\ \lambda_i\mu_i \neq 1 \; \mathrm{for \, all \, } i.
\end{cases}

I was able to verify it in many cases, but so far I could not find a general and easy proof. I suspect that an easy counting argument (that at the moment I do not see) might do the job, so I apologize in advance if the answer to the following question turns out to be trivial.

> **Q.** Is the conjecture above true? If so, what is a clean and simple proof for it?

Comment: Well, If $b\not \equiv 0,\pm 1\pmod p$ then let $\lambda_i=\mu_i\equiv b^{-1}\pmod p$.  Then I'd look at the three exceptions case by case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In fact, I did something along these lines, but I wonder if there is some clever proof avoiding any tedious case-by case analysis.

Comment: Tedious?  It's just three exceptional cases, all of which can be handled in similar ways.  This method gives an explicit construction...I really can't imagine anything simpler.

Comment: Yes, but this is expected to be a technical lemma in a paper, and (if possible) I would prefer some uniform and short proof, since the paper is already quite long. Of course your suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if there is some more conceptual proof (counting argument ?) involving affine geometry over finite fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose arbitrarily $\lambda_i,\,i=1,\cdots,b-1$ and $\mu_i,\,i=1,\cdots,b-2$ such that $\lambda_i\cdot\mu_i\ne1,\,\forall i=1,\cdots,b-2$. (Then $\lambda_b$ is uniquely determined by $\lambda_b=1-\sum_{i=1}^{b-1}\lambda_i$.) Then $\mu_{b-1}$ and $\mu_b$ are subject to conditions: $\mu_{b-1}+\mu_b$ is a constant ($c:=1-\sum_{i=1}^{b-2}\mu_i$), and $\mu_{b-1}\ne\lambda_{b-1}^{-1},\,\mu_{b}\ne\lambda_{b}^{-1}$. The last two conditions are equivalent with $\mu_{b-1}\ne\lambda_{b-1}^{-1},\,c-\lambda_b^{-1}$. If $p>3$ then clearly this is possible as there are more than two non-zero elements in $\mathbb Z_p$. The only case where this is impossible is when $p=3$ and $\left\{\lambda_{b-1}^{-1},\,c-\lambda_b^{-1}\right\}=\left\{1,2\right\}$.

In fact when $p=3$, the condition $\lambda_i\cdot\mu_i\ne1$ implies that $\mu_i=-\lambda_i,\,\forall i$, and hence $\sum_{i=1}^{b}\mu_i=-\sum_{i=1}^{b}\lambda_i=-1$, so it is impossible to find elements satisfying the requirements when $p=3$.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, right. The case $p=3$ is impossible (I did not realize this since for my purposes I needed some big $p$, and then I did not explicitly check this case). Thanks!

Comment: It is my pleasure to help. :-) This question is quite interesting. May I know what the problem in algebraic geometry that led to this question is?

Comment: The existence of these elements allows me to construct a symplectic form on the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-vector space $$V=  H_1(\Sigma_b \times \Sigma_b - \Delta, \, \mathbb{Z}_p) \simeq (\mathbb{Z}_p)^{4b},$$ where $\Sigma_b$ is a smooth projective curve of genus $b$ and $\Delta$ is the diagonal in the product,  related to a certain lifting property that is too long to write in a comment. You can find more details in this preprint (preliminary version, there are imprecision that must be corrected). I will add you to the acknowledgements in the next version.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.03170

Comment: I see, it is an interesting paper. Thanks for sharing.